# C# Nest: How to index array of geo-poinst

Tags: c#, arrays, elasticsearch, nest

Hello I am new to elastic and nest.
I used a example of how to index geo point location that worked fine as  I can see  the geo-points in kibana map visualize.

This is my data structure:

```
public class LocationArray
{
    public string ArrayNameArtical { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.GeoPoint)]
    public IEnumerable<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.GeoPoint)]
    public Coordinate Coordinate { get; set; }
}


public class Coordinate
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
}
```

And my code to index as follow:

```
var response = client.CreateIndex(indexName, s => s
      .AddMapping<Location>(f => f
        .MapFromAttributes() 
        .Properties(p => p
          .GeoPoint(g => g.Name(n => n.Coordinate).IndexGeoHash().IndexLatLon())
        )
      )
    );
    client.IndexMany(new[]{
        new Location
        {
            Name = "Amsterdam",
            Coordinate = new Coordinate { Lat =  52.3740300, Lon = 4.8896900}
        },
        new Location
        {
            Name = "Rotterdam",
            Coordinate = new Coordinate { Lat = 51.9225000, Lon = 4.4791700}
        },
        new Location
        {
            Name = "Utrecht",
            Coordinate = new Coordinate { Lat =  52.0908300,  Lon = 5.1222200}
        },new Location
        {
            Name = "Den Haag",
            Coordinate = new Coordinate { Lat =  52.3740300, Lon = 4.8896900}
        }
    });
```

Now i want to index the LocationArray class, it seems that in need to change my mapping but i colund't figure out how to do it..anyway i can see the array data in kibana but cant view it over map.
Is there any problem with indexing array of geo-point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so after few hours in digging found the way to map this geo-point array..
Hope that one day it will help someone else :)

```
client.Map<LocationArray>(m => m
                        .MapFromAttributes().Properties(p=>p
                            .NestedObject<Location>(no => no
                            .Name(pl => pl.Locations.First())
                            .Dynamic()
                            .Enabled()
                            .IncludeInAll()
                            .IncludeInParent()
                            .IncludeInRoot()
                            .MapFromAttributes()
                            .Path("full")
                            .Properties(pprops => pprops
                                .GeoPoint(ps => ps
                                    .Name(pg => pg.Coordinate)
                                    .IndexGeoHash().IndexLatLon()
                                )
                            )
                        ))
                    );
```